# How to stop greedy behave in regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
text = "March 2 - Liebherr has been awarded the contract to supply the heavy lift crane for DEME's Orion. April - "
x  = re.findall(r'(.* - ?$)', text)
```

I just need it to get the first "March 2 - ", because i wanna remove the dates from the extracted text. the text may be March 22 or any other "month 2 or 1 digit numbers - "
so i need a regex to get them all, but just the first.

Comment: "get them all, but just the first". Um... all or first?

Comment: @StefanPochmann "get them all" > get all months + one or two digit numbers.
"but just the first" > the first item that will satisfy the pattern so it should not get March 2 - dasdasdsd -